# Question about the IEEE latex format

Tags: sectioning

I want to have the section and subsection like in the picture below:

[image]

What are the packages that I need?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). [IEEE](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/) templates can be found here

Comment: how can I use it?

Comment: IEEEtran is a document class, and is loaded the same way you load packages.